# My edit (CRUD) function remove some DATA when I use it

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, crud, symfony-forms, symfony6

i've a problem with symfony project, in my Controller Company when I use edit function to modif some DATA with embedded form, symfony keep only 1 customer (first one) and what I was change and remove all other DATA.

I not understand why symfony do that.

Thank U for Ure help

Best regards

Try to use edit function in symfony with embedded form

Comment: Could you show your `CompanyType` and the form type for the embedded customers?

Comment: Yes sure, here is it
 [CustomerType][1]


[CompanyType][2]


  [1]: https://sharemycode.io/c/3137dcf4e9
  [2]: https://sharemycode.io/c/3137a8f404

Best regards

Comment: Thank you, these look fine. Could you also show your controller edit function, twig template, javascript and `Company`/`Customer` entities again? I saw some of those posted here earlier today, but they seem to have been removed.

Comment: Thank's 
[Company Controller][1]

[Company Entity][2]


[add_or_edit view][3]


[View form][4]


[https://sharemycode.io/c/313a44498e][5]


  [1]: https://sharemycode.io/c/313ee01241
  [2]: https://sharemycode.io/c/3136ec2e55
  [3]: https://sharemycode.io/c/313082321a
  [4]: https://sharemycode.io/c/313817a6be
  [5]: https://JS

I'll add U Customer Entity

Comment: Here's Customer Entity
[Customer Entity][1]


  [1]: https://sharemycode.io/c/313a963fc7

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong function to render the `customer` (and `network` and `process`) subforms, use `form_row(customer)` instead of `form(customer)`:

```
    {% for customer in form.customers %}
        <h6 class="mt-5">Client
            {{_key+1}}</h6>
        {{ form_row(customer) }}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ure right, thank U so much, now all it's ok